# Oracle - Whats the best way to find Partition overhead

Tags: oracle, storage, partitioning

I somehow want to calculate partition overhead for very small tables. I have a Oracle DB with 5K tables sizing from lets say 10KB to 1TB. All of them are range partitioned based on a DATE column. What I want to calculate is the difference in the table size if I will store all data in 1 partition Vs if I store it in lets say 30 partitions. Block Size is 16KB.

Comment: You'll have to describe exactly what you mean and you will find that this formulation already provides the formula you are asking for.

Comment: There's is surely some overhead as each segment (i.e. partition) will have some blocks for space management. This space depends on the tablespace configuration, extent size, ....

Comment: Have you tried this on a development database? Create two tables, one partitioned, one not. Then insert a million records into each. Then select table_name, blocks, round(blocks*16384/1024/1024) as mb from user_tables

Comment: Thanks, @BrianLeach. I applied the same trick and results amazed me. A Non-partitioned table took just 3 MB space, same data stored in 14 daily partitions took 150MB (initial/Next extent set to 10 MB) and with 14*24 hourly partitions (initial/Next extent set to 10 MB) took 3600 MB and currently all my tables are hourly partitions, such a bad design for tiny tables. But like I said I have tables ranging from KB to TB. Thanks guys

Comment: @kapil Your sizes make total sense. Each partition will have a minimum size of 10MB, hence 14 would be (14+1)*10. I would wager that this would not grow as you added more records within a partition.

Comment: I have a data retention policy of 14 days...so at Max there will be 15 full partitions...each day, oldest partition gets dropped and new partitions are created. All tables are in same table space, is there a better way to do this, currently Database is consuming 3 GB space for a table which is actually less than 3MB...I think non-partitioned tables grow in 1MB slots...block size is 16KB